# mysql how to insert multiple values in single column

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables Patient and Details. Patient is related to Details with a foreign key. In Patient one user can have multiple values of Details.

I tried:

```
INSERT INTO `Patients`
        (`patientId`, `name`, `address`, `etage`, 
         `Door`, `Elevator`, `key_number`, `medicineId`, `lid`, 
         `doctorId`) 
VALUES (109, 'Muller', 'bla bla bla ', 3, 
            'links' , 1 , 'S12' ,'m9' , '{02.0 , 2.10 ,2.30}' ,
            'D11');
```

When I try to insert I get the following error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>       (`Sanitas`.`Patients`, CONSTRAINT `Patients_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`lid`)
>       REFERENCES `Details` (`lid`))

Comment: I think you had better show us the Schema for these 2 tables

Comment: The value `'{02.0 , 2.10 ,2.30}'` do not look like values that would be placed in a column called `lid`

Comment: Like @RiggsFolly said, the value `{02.0 , 2.10 ,2.30}` apparently does not exist in your `Details` table.

Comment: you are trying to add a row to your 'Patients' table for which no matching row (lid) is present in 'Details' table. [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: I think you have incorrectly specified your Foreign Key. The Foreign Key should be specified on the `Detail` table and not on the `Patient` table. As you have it you would have to create a **Details** row BEFORE creating the **Patients** row. ___That makes no sense at all___

Comment: I have {02.0 , 2.10 ,2.30} values in my Details table

Comment: **SHOW US THE SCHEMA FOR THESE 2 TABLES!!!!!**

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key means that every row of `Patiens` should have in its column `lid` a value that matches to a value available in the `lid` column of `Details`; most likely, there is no row in `Details` whose `lid` value is `{02.0 , 2.10 ,2.30}`.

With that structure, you should insert that rows once for each `lid` value, but that would lead to other problems (duplicate `patientId` key probably).

This shows some problems in your tables design: what you're describing looks like a `many-to-many` relationship, which requires three tables to be modeled.

The structure you'd need is

```
Patients
    patientId
    name
    address
    etage
    Door
    Elevator
    key_number
    medicineId
    doctorId 
    --notice, no more lid here

Detail
    lid
    --whatever else you have here

PatientsDetail
    patientId
    lid
```

This way you can have a single row for each patient, a single row for each detail, and a table that combines all the combinations of patients and details by associating the ids of those two entities.

The query you wrote would then be split into

```
INSERT INTO `Patients`
    (`patientId`, `name`, `address`, `etage`, `Door`, `Elevator`, `key_number`,
     `medicineId`, `doctorId`) 
VALUES (109, 'Muller', 'bla bla bla ', 3, 'links', 1 , 'S12' ,'m9' , 'D11');

INSERT INTO `PatientsDetail` (`patientId`, `lid`)
VALUES
    (109, 02.0),
    (109, 2.10),
    (109, 2.30);
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution, I will try this.